# content invisible using footer in Android

Tags: android, footer

I am using header, content and footer. but the content part is not visible in fully. some line is invisible. i tried to change the height size in Relative layout also.

here my code

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout 
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              >
         <RelativeLayout      
          android:id="@+id/rl_bike"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:background="@drawable/head" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/details" 
                android:textColor="#fff" 
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:textSize="20dp"/>  


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_back"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/back"
                    android:text="Gebrauchte"
                    android:textColor="#fff" android:textSize="10dp"   android:textStyle="bold">

        </Button>
         </RelativeLayout>

         <ScrollView 
               android:id="@+id/scrollView" 
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_below="@+id/rl_bike">
        <RelativeLayout      
              android:id="@+id/r2_bike"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/rl_bike"
              android:background="#fff">        <RelativeLayout      
              android:id="@+id/r3_bike"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >  
       <TextView 
            android:textSize="20dp" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:id="@+id/txtBikeTitle" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/title" 
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"></TextView>

         <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/image"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="55dp"

               />

             </RelativeLayout>

          <RelativeLayout      
              android:id="@+id/r4_bike"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/r3_bike"
              android:background="#fff">
         <Gallery
              android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/image"
              android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
              android:spacing="10dip">   
          </Gallery>
          </RelativeLayout>
         <RelativeLayout      
              android:id="@+id/r5_bike"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/r4_bike"
              android:background="#fff">


          <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtErst"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="@string/erst"

                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                />

                 <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/erstValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"

               />


                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/km"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="km-Stand :"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtErst">
                </TextView>   
                <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/kmValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/txtErst"
               />

       <View 
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/km"
                android:background="#FF909090" />
       <LinearLayout 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
           android:id="@+id/ll"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           >
         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mdata"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Motor -und Getriebedaten "
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
                />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/hubraum"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
             android:text="Hubraum :"
             android:textColor="#000"
             android:textSize="12dp" 
             android:layout_gravity="left"/>




        <TextView
               android:id="@+id/leistung"

               android:layout_below="@+id/hubValue"/>
                    <TextView
               android:id="@+id/kraftstoff"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:text="Kraftstoff :"
               android:textColor="#000"
               android:textSize="12dp"

               android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
               android:layout_below="@+id/leistungValue" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/> <TextView
              android:id="@+id/antrieb"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Antrieb :"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/kraftstoff"/>      <!--<TextView       <TextView
              android:id="@+id/Getriebe"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:text="getriebe :"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp"

              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/antriebValue"/>

       </LinearLayout>      <View 
              android:id="@+id/l2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dip"
              android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
              android:background="#FF909090" /> 
        <TextView
              android:id="@+id/price"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Preis :"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/l2" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
            <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/priceValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp" 
              android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/l2"
               />     

                 <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/priceSymbol"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="EUR"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/l2"
               android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>   
       <View 
              android:id="@+id/l3"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dip"
              android:layout_below="@+id/price"
              android:background="#FF909090" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>   
       <TextView
              android:id="@+id/farbe"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:text="Farbe :"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/l3"/>  
       <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/farbeValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#000"
               android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
              android:textSize="12dp" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/l3"
               />     
       <View 
              android:id="@+id/l4"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dip"
              android:layout_below="@+id/farbe"
              android:background="#FF909090" />

              <TextView
              android:id="@+id/txtAbs"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:text="ABS"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp"            
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/l4"
              /> <TextView
              android:id="@+id/FID"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:text="FID"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/heizgriffe"/> <TextView
              android:id="@+id/txt_ohlFrwork"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:text="Ohliens frwork"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/FID"/>
                  <TextView
              android:id="@+id/bmw_seitencoffer"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="30dp"
              android:text="BMW-Seitencoffer"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/txt_ohlFrwork"/>  

    <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/bmw_seitencofferValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/bmw_seitencoffer"/>    
                 <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/beschre"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="14dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:text="Beschreibung" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/bmw_seitencofferValue"/>   
                                                 <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/beschreibung"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#000"
              android:textSize="12dp" 
              android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/beschre"/> 

              </RelativeLayout>
         <RelativeLayout  
              android:layout_width="400dp"
              android:layout_height="150dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/r5_bike"

             >
         <RelativeLayout  
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/beschreibung"
              android:background="@drawable/footer"
              android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
              android:layout_marginRight="7dp">

        <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/handle"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="20dp"  
                android:textStyle="bold"  
                android:textSize="12dp" 
                android:textColor="#000" 
                android:text="Haendlerangebot"  
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
               ></TextView>
          <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/link"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="20dp"  
                android:textStyle="bold"  
                android:textSize="12dp" 
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="#000" 
                android:text="website"  
                android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
               ></TextView>


           <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/bikeName"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="20dp"  
                android:textStyle="bold"  
                android:textSize="12dp" 
                android:textColor="#000" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Zitta"  
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/handle">
            </TextView>        
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btn_footarrow"
                 android:layout_width="30dp"
                 android:layout_height="30dp"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/bikeName"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="260dp"
                 android:background="@drawable/arrow" />
            <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/txtWebLand"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="20dp"  
                android:textStyle="bold"  
                android:textSize="10dp" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#000" 
                android:text=""  
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bikeName">

              </TextView>    
             <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/address"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="20dp"  
                android:textStyle="bold"  
                android:textSize="10dp" 
                android:gravity="center_vertical"

                android:textColor="#000" 
                android:text="@string/address"  
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtWebLand">

              </TextView>  

               <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/telNoName"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="15dp"  
                 android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="10dp" 
                android:textColor="#000" 

                android:text="Tel:"  
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/address"/> <TextView  
                android:id="@+id/faxName"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="15dp"  
                 android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="10dp" 
                android:textColor="#000"               
                android:text="Fax :"               
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/telNoName">

              </TextView>              

           </RelativeLayout>     
                      </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout> 

    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#fff">
        <WebView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

        </WebView>
    </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Last fax no is missing and that rectangle box is not visible in fully. if i am not using the footer view mean its working fine. what's the issue heere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know with your code, I guess either you recopied your xml file more than once, or you have not separated out your xml file. Whatever is the case. Edit your question, and post your question properly.

Apart from that, as far as your answer is concern you can use android:layout_weight="" for separating out your layout and get proper alignment to your screen. Try that out. If any problem let me know.